# Is it possible to stake spl-token?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, solana-cli

I am trying to develop a marketplace where users who have my spl-tokens can stake it and get rewarded. Is it possible in solana? If yes, some references will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to stake any SPL token.

Comment: For example, this is an NFT staking program https://github.com/gemworks/gem-farm. As we know NFT is nothing but a type of SPL Token.